# Google BigQuery REST API C# copy/export table with nested schema as CSV

Tags: c#, rest, api, google-bigquery

Is there a way to export a whole table with a nested schema from Google BigQuery using the REST API as a CSV?

There is an example for doing this (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) with a not nested schema. This works fine on the not nested columns in my table. Here is the code of this part:

```
PagedEnumerable<TableDataList, BigQueryRow> result2 = client.ListRows(datasetId, result.Reference.TableId);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var row in result2)
        {
            sb.Append($"{row["visitorId"]}, {row["visitNumber"]}, {row["totals.hits"]}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString())))
        {
            var obj = gcsClient.UploadObject(bucketName, fileName, contentType, stream);
        }
```

In BQ there are columns like totals.hits, totals.visits...If I try to address them  I got the errormessage that there is not such a column. If I am addressing "totals" I get the objectname "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]" in the rows in my csv.

Is there any possibility to do something like that? In the end I want my table from GA in BQ as a CSV somewhere else.

Comment: Forget about .NET or the obvious formatting bug - how would a CSV with a nested table look like? Where would the nested headers and data go?  CSV is a *simple* format for tabular data. What you ask is definitely not that.

Comment: How are you going to use that data? Import it to another database? Process it yourself? Feed it to R? Do you really want that nested structure? You could use JSON, especially line-separated JSON if you have a lot of data. Or you could flatten the original data first (preferably in the *original* query, not the client) and export a normal CSV file

Comment: The destination of the data is Azure Blob Storage (and after that Azure ML). I´d like to have an automatically export of the whole table (it is a daily generated table from GA in BQ) into the blob storage as a csv for further analysis. So I try to get the data using Google REST API, doing the transformation in this program and store the file using the Microsoft REST API. The CSV should/can look like a csv generated from BQ. I mean repeated data after unnesting is fine. Just want to get an unnested table like I can get in BQ.

Comment: Then unnest it in BQ and export the unnested results. Why do such a conversion in your client code? In any case, your code doesn't show *what* is in a `totals` row. You'll have to do some sort of loop to get each item.

Comment: The error itself shows that `totals` is a `Dictionary<string,object>`. You can get individual values with `totals["hits"]` etc, as long as you know the field names are. Or you can use `String.Join(","totals.Values)` to join all of the dictionary's values in a single step. Values in [Dictionary.Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) use the same order as `Dictionary.Keys`. You can use `String.Join(",",tables.Keys)` to generate the header for the nested table

Comment: I don´t do it in BQ, because I get a table every day and in the end the program should act on its own to get the table every day from BQ into blob as a csv. To get this transfer without touching it it is necessary to do this in the code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don´t understand the Dictionary solution. How can I access the columns?

Comment: There are no columns. The strange object name says that the  `totals` field contains a `Dictionary<string,object>`. When you call `ToString()` on an arbitrary object, the default behaviour inherited from `Object.ToString()` is to print the type name. Store the dictionary somewhere, eg `Dictionary<string,object> totals=row["totals"];` and access the items in it just like any dictionary, eg `totals["hits"]`will return the value for `hits`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Select every column you need like in the following shema und flatten everything was need to be flattened.

```
string query = $@"
#legacySQL
SELECT
  visitorId,
  visitNumber,
  visitId,
  visitStartTime,
  date,
  hits.hitNumber as hitNumber,
  hits.product.productSKU as product.productSKU
FROM 
  FLATTEN(FLATTEN({tableName},hits),hits.product)";

//Creating a job for the query and activating legacy sql

            BigQueryJob job = client.CreateQueryJob(query,
                new CreateQueryJobOptions { UseLegacySql = true });

            BigQueryResults queryResult = client.GetQueryResults(job.Reference.JobId,
                new GetQueryResultsOptions());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//Getting the headers from the GA table and write them into the first row of the new table

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= queryResult.Schema.Fields.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                string columenname = "";
                var header = queryResult.Schema.Fields[0].Name;
                if (i + 1 >= queryResult.Schema.Fields.Count)
                    columenname = queryResult.Schema.Fields[i].Name;
                else
                    columenname = queryResult.Schema.Fields[i].Name + ",";
                sb.Append(columenname);
            }

//Getting the data from the GA table and write them row by row into the new table

            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (var row in queryResult.GetRows())
            {

                count++;
                if (count % 1000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine($"item {count} finished");
                int blub = queryResult.Schema.Fields.Count;
                for (Int64 j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt64(blub); j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (row.RawRow.F[Convert.ToInt32(j)] != null)
                            sb.Append(row.RawRow.F[Convert.ToInt32(j)].V + ",");

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            }
```